# optimizing indexing and retrieval of elements in numpy arrays in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy, cython

I'm trying to optimize the following code, potentially by rewriting it in Cython: it simply takes a low dimensional but relatively long numpy arrays, looks into of its columns for 0 values, and marks those as -1 in an array. The code is:

```
import numpy as np

def get_data():
    data = np.array([[1,5,1]] * 5000 + [[1,0,5]] * 5000 + [[0,0,0]] * 5000)
    return data

def get_cols(K):
    cols = np.array([2] * K)
    return cols

def test_nonzero(data):
    K = len(data)
    result = np.array([1] * K)
    # Index into columns of data
    cols = get_cols(K)
    # Mark zero points with -1
    idx = np.nonzero(data[np.arange(K), cols] == 0)[0]
    result[idx] = -1

import time
t_start = time.time()
data = get_data()
for n in range(5000):
    test_nonzero(data)
t_end = time.time()
print (t_end - t_start)
```

`data` is the data. `cols` is the array of columns of data to look for non-zero values (for simplicity, I made it all the same column). The goal is to compute a numpy array, `result`, which has a 1 value for each row where the column of interest is non-zero, and -1 for the rows where the corresponding columns of interest have a zero.

Running this function 5000 times on a not-so-large array of 15,000 rows by 3 columns takes about 20 seconds. Is there a way this can be sped up? It appears that most of the work goes into finding the nonzero elements and retrieving them with indices (the call to `nonzero` and subsequent use of its index.) Can this be optimized or is this the best that can be done? 
How could a Cython implementation gain speed on this?

Comment: The nonzero is a good try (not sure if it helps much or at all though). If you are desperate and know cols are valid, you could try making a linear index. If K is constant in the loop, you could not redo the np.arange every time too...

Answer (score 2):

```
cols = np.array([2] * K)
```

That's going to be really slow. That's create a very large python list and then converts it into a numpy array. Instead, do something like:

```
cols = np.ones(K, int)*2
```

That'll be way faster

```
result = np.array([1] * K)
```

Here you should do:

```
result = np.ones(K, int)
```

That will produce the numpy array directly.

```
idx = np.nonzero(data[np.arange(K), cols] == 0)[0]
result[idx] = -1
```

The cols is an array, but you can just pass a 2. Furthermore, using nonzero adds an extra step.

```
idx = data[np.arange(K), 2] == 0
result[idx] = -1
```

Should have the same effect.

Comment: thanks but `cols` is not part of the computation, it's just an example. and as I mentioned, cols is not always just one value like 2 -- I just made it that for simplicity. it's usually a vector will different columns. so I don't think these suggestions speed it up

Comment: @user248237dfsf, ok, I missed the part about cols not being real. However, `numpy.array([2] * K)` is really really slow, and its why the code as it stands is slow. Without seeing your real code I can't really guess why it would be slow.